# Долго загружаются данные от Api через цикл Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста я что то делаю не так или это сайт так отдает долго данные?

короткое видео с запросом
https://yadi.sk/d/X3fpSPWlVfx95w

```
// Получение колличества дней запрошенного периода
    $end_date_time = strtotime($end_date);
    $start_date_time = strtotime($start_date);
    $days_period = $end_date_time - $start_date_time;
    $quantity_days = $days_period / 86400;
```

// Получение по API праздников
    $arr = [];

```
    for($i=0; $i <= $quantity_days; $i++)
    {
        $add_day_unix = strtotime("+$i day", strtotime($start_date));
        $add_day = date("Y-m-d", $add_day_unix);
        $api_date = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.sm.su/v1/calendar/business/?day='.$add_day),1);

        if($api_date['work'] == 0) {

            $arr[] = $add_day;
        }

    }
```

Comment: сначала api запросите а потом уже ответ разбирайте, даже 30 отдельных запросов по 0.3 секунды уже в 9 секунд выльються

Comment: а как правильно будет в моем случае запросить? если у меня в любом случае через цикл массив необходимых дат запрашивается

Comment: multi curl и вы получите ответы асинхронно

Comment: можно пример на моем коде пожалуйста? а то пока что не понял до конца..

Comment: [Рабочий пример](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-exec.php). Разберитесь в нем и адаптируйте для своего кода.